# AntiForgeryToken in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-window

I am opening an kendo window using the below jquery function.

I need to pass `__RequestVerificationToken` to the MVC Controller because I am having `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` Attribute.

However, I am not able to pass it. Can you please suggest how to pass `__RequestVerificationToken` while opening an kendoWindow

```
function OpenTest() {               
    var url = '@Url.ActionWithArea("OpenTest", "Test", GlobalConst.AREA_Test)';
    url += "?test=" +$("#test").val() + "&test1=" +$("#test1").val();

    windowElement = $('<div id = "abc" />').kendoWindow({
        title: 'test',
        content: url,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false, 
        width: 900,
        height: 400,
        close: function () {              
                windowElement.destroy(); 
            }).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make a POST request when loading the template which would allow you to send your antiforgery token:

```
content: {
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        '__RequestVerificationToken': 'the value of your token'
    }
},
```